# C# signed and unsigned integers are Narrowing conversion both ways?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, type-conversion, narrowing

As per the MSDN article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s682k58%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

> Explicit conversion is required by some compilers to support narrowing
>   conversions..

Based on the statements made in the above msdn link, is it safe to say that

Converting int to uint is narrowing conversion

Also,

Converting uint to int is narrowing conversion

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting an integral or floating point type from signed to unsigned and vice-versa is neither a narrowing nor a widening conversion, since the number of bits used to store it remains unchanged.

Instead, it is a change of representation and can utterly change the number (e.g. signed -1 is converted to unsigned 0xffffffff).

In fact, if you use unchecked arithmetic:

```
unchecked
{
    int  x = -1;
    uint y = (uint) x;
    int  z = (int) y;

    Debug.Assert(x == z); // Will succeed for all x.

    uint a = 0xffffffff;
    int  b = (int) a;
    uint c = (uint) b;

    Debug.Assert(a == c); // Will succeed for all a.
}
```

So a round trip works in both directions, which proves that narrowing does not occur in either direction.

Narrowing and widening only applies to integral and floating point types where a different number of bits are used to store one or more parts of the number.

However, because the number's value can be changed, you must cast to make such a conversion, to ensure that you don't do it accidentally.

Answer (score 1):

It is not narrowing, but you must still be explicit. Both can hold values that the other doesn't have. `int` can hold negative values, which `uint` can't and `uint` can hold values greater than 2147483647, which is the maximum value for an `int`.

However, both `int` and `uint` use 32 bits (= 4 bytes) to hold information.
When you convert an `int` to a `byte`, you will lose information, because a `byte` can only hold 8 bits.
Converting between `int` and `uint` doesn't lose any bits, but the bits have a different meaning. (in 50% of the cases)
You must be explicit about it to indicate that you know what you are doing. It will prevent mistakes that would be caused by an implicit cast.